# Resize video to fit on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was wondering how you can resize a video so it fits on a mobile screen. The video fits fine on the computer, but on mobile the video is too large and it is cut off. What should I do?

I am using Avada theme on WordPress.

My website: http://dcnytours.com

Comment: you use google drive video embed which is not responsive. try responsive embed using one of methods in this tutorail https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 2):

Limit `iframe` so it doesn't go out of view:

```
#post-10 iframe {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

You could also make it a little bit bigger just for mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) {
#post-10 .fusion-column-wrapper {
padding: 0;
margin: -20px;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your iframe in a div and add some styling to it. Your html would be simple like so:

```
<div class="videowrapper">
    <iframe ...>
</div>
```

You also need a little bit of css to make the wrapper responsive and the video fill that wrapper:

```
.videowrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
}

.videowrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

check out this fiddle to see it in action. The container width decides the video width and it will scale (in a 16:9 format, adjust the top padding for another format)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck417g3e/1/)

You might want to add the videowrapper class to the

tag in the fusion-text div in your example, but it might ask for some creative padding margins...